# Can we make a new tag for puzzles that are like chess puzzles, but generalised to all games, and also specific to those kinds of puzzles

Tags: discussion, tags

[Example question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56997/simple-homeworlds-puzzle)

So, I make or have made a puzzle where someone has to find a move sequence in a certain number of moves or achieve some other objective just like a chess puzzle. however, there is no specific tag for this kind of puzzle that I can tell.

Even confined to chess, [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) is not specific enough, and can include puzzles where chess is involved, but maybe not even played. and also even if it were specific enough, it would be confined only to chess.

anyway, we need a tag for these kinds of puzzles. I do not think [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) is sufficient either. [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) is used for multiple puzzle types, including simple game theory style games, where you play from the start and solve the entire game. I think solving an entire game is far different from solving a chess puzzle and such.

anyway, ideally when the puzzle tag is made, chess puzzles will be tagged: [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) [undecided tag], and other such puzzles may be tagged: [board-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games) [undecided tag]

## Is this a good tag to have, and if so, what should it be called?

Answer (score 2):

I think [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) is fine in this instance.

From the tag wiki (emphasis mine):

> A puzzle whose solution is a methodological plan of action for realizing a specific goal as effectively as possible. The solution, rather than being an object or word or single action, specifies **how to act in a multi-step interaction**, basing each action off of previous actions not under your control. **Often, this is in a turn-based game played against an adversary**.

Yes, [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) and [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) can be somewhat vague, and are used for multiple puzzle types, but when used together leave a relatively clear indication of what the puzzle is about (there are of course edge cases, but no tagging system will ever be perfect). Tags, by design, are broad-ish blobs, which when used in conjunction with each other create more specific Venn intersections.

Comment: "A puzzle whose solution is a methodological plan of action for realizing a specific goal as effectively as possible." In my opinion, I wouldn't say that the solution to a chess puzzle is really a plan. Even if it is, Strategy is still incredibly vague. for example, [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/gambling-in-a-rigged-casino) is tagged strategy, however i would say that this is almost nothing like a chess puzzle.

Comment: @DestructibleLemon I agree with Alconja. A strategy is not a single solution path, but a plan that covers all possible outcomes. This is true of chess and other two player turn based games.

Comment: @thecoder16 I'd say the strategy in strategy tagged challenges tends to be different from the strategy in chess puzzles and such. Also, puzzles tagged chess and strategy seem to be rather distinct from chess puzzles, whereas chess puzzles seem to be more likely to be tagged chess without the strategy tag. Hence, the strategy tag appears to be used in almost the exact opposite way you propose.

Comment: @DestructibleLemon - I think (and it sounds like we're on the same page here) there are two "types" of strategy questions, generalised strategies ("plans"), vs specific strategies ("steps"). The example in your comment is the former, and you're proposing a new tag for the latter. Where we differ in opinion, is that I think it's ok for a tag to be a bit fuzzy especially when the bigger picture of multiple overlapping tags is considered. I'd argue chess+strategy will almost always be "steps", and, say, probability+strategy will almost always be "plans". Thereby removing the ambiguity (mostly).

Comment: @DestructibleLemon - all that being said, this is my opinion, and I'm happy to be outvoted. I'd just (again, personally) be wary of introducing new tags if A) they're not strictly needed, B) they won't get used much, C) they create more confusion. Here, I think A holds (hence my answer above), B is questionable and C is somewhat likely, unless you can come up with a brilliant name. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider when naming the tag:

chess puzzles ≈ chess problems ≈ chess composition

many of the types of chess compositions have the substring mate in them:

- directmate
- helpmate
- reflexmate
- etc.

this could be used in the name, following the theme e.g [gamemate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamemate). Though some games do not have checkmates, I feel like it can still apply in terms of analogy even though that specific part is not the same, because any directmate puzzle can be converted to a chess-without-checkmate puzzle by adding one move. Another one on the same thing [compositionmate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compositionmate). the only problem is these are not standard

chess composition could be changed to game composition, but this seems rather vague and confusing to me. Composition puzzle similarly is confusing

another option [mate-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mate-puzzle) perhaps, or [puzzlemate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzlemate), though the first possibly seems too specific to chess?

and for some verbose ones:

- [game-sequence-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-sequence-puzzle)
- [generalized-chess-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalized-chess-puzzle) (I would have spelt it "generalised", but i guess people here will probably spell in AmE)
- [game-state-solution-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-state-solution-puzzle)

are any of these decent?

Comment: One goal for tags is to make them easily findable when searching for tags.  I think all of your earlier proposals fail in that regard (no one will find a [tag:gamemate] tag unless they already know it exists and are looking for it).  Also, putting "puzzle" into the tag name is redundant, since almost all posts on this site are puzzles...